# Query not using case insensitive indexes with a case-insensitive regex?

Tags: mongodb

Heyo, trying to figure out why Mongo is not using a case insensitive index for a query. We have both case-sensitive and case-insensitive indexes for our fields:

`{
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "name.firstName" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name.firstName_1",
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "name.lastName" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name.lastName_1",
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "email" : 1
                },
                "name" : "email_1",
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "email" : 1
                },
                "name" : "email_1_insensitive",
                "background" : true,
                "collation" : {
                        "locale" : "en_US",
                        "caseLevel" : false,
                        "caseFirst" : "off",
                        "strength" : 1,
                        "numericOrdering" : false,
                        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
                        "maxVariable" : "punct",
                        "normalization" : false,
                        "backwards" : false,
                        "version" : "57.1"
                }
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "name.lastName" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name.lastName_1_insensitive",
                "ns" : "movement_prod_centrio.parties",
                "background" : true,
                "collation" : {
                        "locale" : "en_US",
                        "caseLevel" : false,
                        "caseFirst" : "off",
                        "strength" : 1,
                        "numericOrdering" : false,
                        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
                        "maxVariable" : "punct",
                        "normalization" : false,
                        "backwards" : false,
                        "version" : "57.1"
                }
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "name.firstName" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name.firstName_1_insensitive",
                "ns" : "movement_prod_centrio.parties",
                "background" : true,
                "collation" : {
                        "locale" : "en_US",
                        "caseLevel" : false,
                        "caseFirst" : "off",
                        "strength" : 1,
                        "numericOrdering" : false,
                        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
                        "maxVariable" : "punct",
                        "normalization" : false,
                        "backwards" : false,
                        "version" : "57.1"
                }
        },`

However, when we then search with a case insensitive query, the case-insensitive indexes are not used.

`find { find: "parties", filter: { $or: [ { email: { $in: [ /^abc/i ] } }, { name.firstName: { $in: [ /^abc/i ] } }, { name.lastName: { $in: [ /^abc/i ] } } ] }, projection: { topicId: 1, email: 1, name.firstName: 1, name.lastName: 1 }, limit: 100, maxTimeMS: 5000, collation: { locale: "en_US", strength: 1 } } planSummary: IXSCAN { name.firstName: 1 }, IXSCAN { email: 1 }, IXSCAN { name.lastName: 1 } keysExamined:385759 docsExamined:131837 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:3027 nreturned:27 reslen:5055 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 6056 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3028 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 3028 } } } protocol:op_query 2347ms`

We can see that the query is not using the case insensitive regex both by the # docsExamined and also by checking the plan, which uses the `"indexName" : "name.firstName_1",` indexes. Have been checking the docs extensively, but haven't been able to find anything we're doing wrong here. Any thoughts?

Comment: My best guess would be that possibly a case-insensitive regex is not mapped to a collation with equivalent strength? Based on documentation saying "To use an index that specifies a collation, query and sort operations must specify the same collation as the index. If a collection has defined a collation, all queries and indexes inherit that collation unless they explicitly specify a different collation."

Comment: If that is the case, does anybody know which (if at all) collation strength a case-insensitive regex is mapped to? Or do you have to manually specify collation for any queries with a case-insensitive regex (assuming changing collation for the entire collection is not viable)

Comment: Verified ^ is not the case; same query uses the insensitive on my local with equivalent regexes =/

Comment: As at MongoDB 3.6: "Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and is unable to utilize case-insensitive indexes." (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)

Comment: Thanks for the link, super helpful. Not sure how it was able to use the case-insensitive indexes on my local then given the equivalent query.

Comment: It is possible for an index to be selected for a case-insensitive regex but not used efficiently (check the `keysExamined`, `docsExamined`, and `nReturned` values). You can improve the index usage for a prefix regex by storing lowercase values (for example, `/^abc/` will be an efficient query since the values match what is stored in the index).